# django - order_with_respect_to recursive foreign key

Tags: django, recursion, key

I am using Django 1.2.3.  I have a table that represents categories and subcategories.  For subcategories, it just references a 'parent' primary key from its own table as its parent.  It looks something like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = 'Category'
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
        ordering = ['display_weight', 'name']
        order_with_respect_to = 'parent'
    name = models.CharField('Category Name', max_length=32)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    display_weight = models.IntegerField('Display Weight', default=50)
```

WHen I attempt to validate/sync this database, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no
>   attribute 'get_category_order'

It seems that it won't let me order with respect to a "foreign key" that is recursive.  Can anyone explain this.  Is there a way around this?  There might be several levels of categories and subcategories, but there will never be cyclic references defined in the table.

Comment: That's strange, I tried it with South, it works pretty well. Do you use South in your Django project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [**`changeset`**](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13241) shows that the your issue has been fixed in the version of django you are using. It is a backport of this [**`changeset`**](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/14045).

The issue is discussed here in these tickets:

> http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2740
>
> http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13241

You might want to check if your django has the patched code.

Comment: Thanks kriegar, this ticket had my object defined almost exactly as I have.  It appears to be a straight-ahead bug.  I downloaded the diff for the base.py and applied it as a patch to the file in the .deb package in ubuntu, but I still seem to be getting the same error message.